# Dynamically sized tableview in UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

This might take a little explaining.  I have a UIViewController subclass that contains a label and a tableview directly underneath (the label and some other controls being the reason I can't use a UITableViewController subclass).  Because the tableview contents are dynamic, I can't set it's height directly when I add it.  So, I am doing the following in loadView:

```
//add the table view with no size for now
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

//now that the datasource is set, use the delegates to update the height
    [tableView layoutIfNeeded];
    [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.y_position, 320, [tableView contentSize].height)];

//add it to my scrollview, which contains all controls in this view
    [scrollView addSubview:tableView];
```

This works well so far (though alternative ideas would be nice to hear).

The problem comes when I enter edit mode for my view.  I want to modify the contents of the table view, inserting an additional section and row.  So far, I have the following implementation of setEditing:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{   
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    //insert or remove the section and row 
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
    if (self.isEditing) {
        [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    else {
        [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }

    [nameAndIngredientsTableView endUpdates];
```

}

The additional section and row are added just fine, but the bottom rows of the table view are cut off since it's size hasn't been updated.  How should I do this?

I attempted to use the same code again - layoutIfNeeded and then setting the height manually, but this doesn't seem to do anything

I'd love to know what I should be looking at to dynamically resize the tableview when coming in and out of edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave open up in case there are better solutions, but I could only get this to work by calculating the new height manually and also animating manually:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [nameAndIngredientsTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, tableView.frame.origin.y, 320, tableView.frame.size.height + delta)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

where delta is +x for an insert and -x for a removal.  x is currently being determined by trial and error, which isn't ideal, but i'm working on deriving it from tableView.rowHeight, .sectionHeaderHeight and .sectionFooterHeight

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are trying to show all the row without scrolling.  (If your app is ok with scrolling, then last row cut off is not an issue right?)

A better way to manage this is to play with the row height.  You fix the frame height.  Then compute the rowHeight as frameHeight/NumberOfRows.

Hope this helps